# How to get the last of a kind in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi there I have this in mysql.

```
record rate update
   1      1      1
   2      1      2
   3      1      3
   4      1      4
   5      2      1
   6      2      2
   7      3      1
   8      3      2
   9      3      3
```

I want to select the rows with the last update of each rate.

For example:

```
the last row of rate 1 is (4 1 4),     
the last row of rate 2 is (6 2 2)     
and the last row of rate 3 is (9 3 3).
```

Comment: why `javascript` is tagged in this question?

Comment: @brk May be he uses it in is technology stack..

Comment: Would it not be better to log a time/date stamp for each entry?

Comment: No because I use the number of the update in links.

Comment: do rate and update always increase as record increases?

Comment: Incidentally, this is the most frequently asked question under this tag

Comment: Yes. It inserts a new record every time a user updates any rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select max(record), rate, max(update)
from your_table
group by rate
```